# GWT 2.0 & CSS Resource Bundles

Tags: gwt

I have a GWT 2.0 ToggleButton that I have styled from a ResourceBundle:

```
ToggleButton tb = new ToggleButton();
tb.setStyleName(MyResources.INSTANCE.MyCssResource().TogBut());
```

The client side implementation then adds additional styles to the  "TogBut-up" and "TogBut-down" for the styling of the states of the button.

I can't however add a style like "TogBut-down" to my css because that is an invalid name for a field in my CssResource subclass interface.

Does anyone know what best practice is in this scenario? Should I just avoid obfuscation and resource bundles all together?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use whatever css class names that you want by using the @ClassName annotation

```
String TogBut();
@ClassName("TogBut-up")
String TogButUp();
@ClassName("TogBut-down")
String TogButDown();
```

In the css you have:

```
.TogBut{
 ...
}
.TogBut-up{
 ...
}
.TogBut-down{
 ...
}
```

Google's docs about this: http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideClientBundle.html#Constants

Answer (score 1):

What I ended up having to do was create multiple styles for the different states, so my bundle contained methods like this:

```
String TogBut();
String TogButUp();
String TogButDown();
```

Comment: Thanks, I did try this, but the GWT compiler obfuscated each of the css entries to different things, so when the ToggleBuggton added the -down style the two css classes didn't match. I ended up adding @exclude to the top of my css.

Comment: What about `MyResources.INSTANCE.MyCssResource().TogBut() + "-down"`? (can't test it atm, but if the client code adds the "-down" suffix to the obfuscated style name it should work)

Comment: @Tegan Clark

Well what I was suggesting was not adding -down to the style, but simply adding the separate style. So originally do `setStyleName(resource.TogBut())` and then later `addStyleName(resource.TogButUp())`. They won't look related in the obfuscated CSS, but they will work.